# Mongoose schema Item returns undefined discord.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

I'm trying to set up my Discord bot with mongoDB using Mongoose, but I am stuck with a problem.

I connected my bot to my database like so:

```
mongoose.connect(ENV.MONGODB_SRV, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
}).then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to mongoDB database")
}).catch((e) => {
    console.log("MongoDB error is " + e)
});
```

I created a simple mongoose schema with some currency:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const profileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userID: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    serverID: { type: String, required: true },
    money: { type: Number, default: 100 },
    deposit: {type: Number }
});

const model = new mongoose.model("profileModels", profileSchema);

module.exports = model
```

I made so that when a user joins the server, the bot will create a profile for them (`guildMemberAdd`), and/or if user uses a command, which in my case is a slash command, the bot will also create a profile if they don't already have one. (this code is under the `interactionCreate` event, but it is the same as the one in `guildMemberAdd`).

```
const profileModel = require("../../schemas/profileSchema");

let profileData;
try {
    profileData = await profileModel.findOne({ userID: interaction.user.id});

    if (!profileData) {
        let profile = await profileModel.create({
            userID: interaction.user.id,
            serverID: interaction.guildId,
            money: 100,
            deposit: 0
        });
        
        profile.save();
    }
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
try {

    await command.execute(client, interaction, Discord, profileData);
}
catch (error) {

    console.log(`The interaction error is ${error}`);

    await interaction.reply({ content: "There was an error trying to execute this command. ", ephemeral: true});
}
```

And when I check the profile in Robo 3T, it gets created correctly, with all the attributes and so. but when I try to access an attribute it always returns `undefined`. Here's an example command where it returns `undefined`:

```
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("balance")
    .setDescription("Check your balance!"),

    async execute(client, interaction, profileData) {

        interaction.reply("Your current money balance is " + inlineCode(profileData.money) + "!" );
    }
}
```

I tried for 3 hours, and I can't figure out why. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You forgot to include how you call `execute`.

Comment: You're right, thank you. I edited my question

Comment: You call `await command.execute()` with a total of 4 arguments, while your command is expecting 3 parameters. See if fixing this resolves your issue.

Comment: Glad I could help :)